# Calculate gears rotation for a realtime simulation

Tags: physics, rotation, simulations

I'm trying to do a game with real time simulations of gears. There is a big Gear with inside a smaller gear.

I managed to draw gears with different diameters but equal size teeth, but if i try to move the smaller one inside the bigger one the movement is odd.

See the animated gif:

[image]

The biggest gear is in center C1 and the small in the center C2. I calculate C2 position in this way:

```
C2.x = C1.x + C1_RADIUS-C2_RADIUS) * cos(t);
C2.y = C1.y - C1_RADIUS-C2_RADIUS) * sin(t);
```

for t that goes from 0 to TWO_PI in n steps.

I apply as rotation the angle t, but maybe it is wrong and i have to calculate another rotation for get a perfect joint.

#### EDIT:

I am using radians for rotations and I think this is OK.

***My main problem is that I want to achieve a perfect joint between teeth like [this example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/gears.html). My teeth are overlapping in some odd way.***

### EDIT

a **working** example can be found here: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/83665

Comment: I only see the small gear teeth rotating very slowly. But the inner green cross spinning at what looks like the correct speed. Is the main problem getting the drawing of the teeth rotating or finding the correct rotation speed? Common issue to check here is if you're using radians.

Comment: i have edited the question a little bit..

Comment: It reminds a shader i wrote some time ago : http://glsl.heroku.com/e#3738.0. what you should take in account here is gear ratio. ratio = number of teeth gear A / number of teeth gear B. use that ratio to scale rotation speed of main gear vs second gear.

Comment: Can you please make a new animated GIF when your problem is fixed? Looking at the “wrong” one is so frustrating :-)

Comment: still some problem if the gear is outside. i have found some dirty number to add to try to resolve problem but nothing do to.. if you have some idea..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The large gear has circumference `2πR1` and the small one has circumference `2πR2`, so when the small gear has made a full circle, it has turned `R1/R2` times around itself, **minus one** time because it turned inside the large gear (it would be plus one if the gear was outside).

So when the centre of the inner gear is rotated by angle `t`, the gear itself needs to be rotated by angle `(R1/R2-1)t`.

If the values you handle are tooth counts `N1` and `N2` you can replace `R1/R2` with `N1/N2`.

There is also the issue of the initial rotation. Let `a` be the angle value `atan2(C2.y - C1.y, C2.x - C1.x)`. Apply initial  rotation `a` to gear 1. If gear 2 is inside, apply rotation `a` to it, too. If gear 2 is outside, apply a `π+a+h` rotation where `h = π/(2*N2)` is the half angle of a tooth.

Comment: thanks. this did the trick perfectly. can you give me more information on how to find this formula?

Comment: I must admit my knowledge of gear mathematics only comes from 30 years of playing with Legos. If I come across a meaningful resource I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @nkint It is the number of teeth that counts. You can just replace the radius ratio `R1/R2` with the tooth count ration `N1/N2`.

Comment: ok perfect, thanks, now it is more clear. i have googled for "gear ratio" but i don't find anywhere the +1 or -1 for outside/inside

Comment: tue to the fact that there are still some problems i unchecked the correct answer.. and i have upload all the code, maybe someone one day will have a look to the last unresolved problem!

Comment: @nkint: just replace `big.getTeethAngle()` with `2 * big.getTeethAngle()` in both `example0` and `example2`.

Comment: jeah it works for radius 80-60 but if you change the radius it is broken again. Try 60/40, 80/70, 100/30 and there are errors again.. :( quite frustrating, probabilly the Gear class i a little bit messy and I have to rewrite it from scratch

Comment: @nkint: Ah, I see. The rotating speed is correct, it's only the start position that needs fixing. You'll need to fix your Gear class so that the initial position can be specified.

Comment: do you have any ideas on how has to be specified? i mean, does it have to be in some kind of relation with the gear ratio? with the teeth angle? with the radius?

Comment: @nkint: I have added formulas for the initial rotations. Hope this helps.

Comment: i haven't understand the atan part. and i didn't use it. and i don't fully understand the math of -1, +1, and for the two rotating gears the rotation of smaller gear is: t*(R1/R2-1)*(R1/R2).... anyway, now it works, thank. if you find more accurate math that explain that please add to post (and to comment otherways i will not be noticed about it) or play with the code in openprocessing.org, it works! thank you!

Comment: ps. i added you also in the openprocessing.org, tell me if you want me to remove it

Comment: Gnnnn, what is this sign: "π" ???

Comment: @john_b that's the simbol for PI